# Nested embeddable - AttributeOverride for embeddable within embeddable

Tags: hibernate, jpa, embeddable

I have class Money which is an @Embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class Money implements Serializable, Comparable<Money> {
    @Column(name = "amount", precision = 15, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

When I useit multiple time inside entity, everything works fine. For example

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "entry"))
    private Money entryValue;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "leave"))
    private Money leaveValue;
}
```

Code above works perfectly.

Now the problem occurs when I have another @Embeddable that I want to have Money instances in it and that @Embeddable is used by an entity multiple times. Example:

1. Embeddable

   ```
   @Embeddable
   public class ReportCostValues implements Serializable {

       @Embedded
       @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "covered_by_grant"))
       private Money coveredByGrant;

       @Embedded
       @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "own_resources"))
       private Money foundedFromOwnResources;

       @Embedded
       @AttributeOverride(name = "amount", column = @Column(name = "personal_contribution"))
       private Money personalContribution;
   ```
2. Entity

   ```
    @Entity
    public class ReportCostEntity implements Identifiable<Long>, Serializable {

       @Id
       private Long id;

       @Embedded       
       private ReportCostValues contracted;

       @Embedded       
       private ReportCostValues current;

       @Embedded        
       private ReportCostValues previousReport;
   ```

This code above will not work. Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Hi you have to use `@AttributeOverrides` judicially,you have to override attributes once again  in entity that you have done in embeddable `ReportCostValues` class, hope code below is what you are looking for.

```
@Entity 
public class ReportCostEntity implements  Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Embedded   
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="coveredByGrant.amount", column = @Column(name="contracted_coveredByGrant") ),
        @AttributeOverride(name="foundedFromOwnResources.amount", column = @Column(name="contracted_foundedFromOwnResources")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="personalContribution.amount", column = @Column(name="contracted_personalContribution"))
    } )
    private ReportCostValues contracted;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="coveredByGrant.amount", column = @Column(name="current_coveredByGrant") ),
        @AttributeOverride(name="foundedFromOwnResources.amount", column = @Column(name="current_foundedFromOwnResources")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="personalContribution.amount", column = @Column(name="current_personalContribution"))
    } )
    private ReportCostValues current;

    @Embedded 
    @AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name="coveredByGrant.amount", column = @Column(name="previousReport_coveredByGrant") ),
        @AttributeOverride(name="foundedFromOwnResources.amount", column = @Column(name="previousReport_foundedFromOwnResources")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="personalContribution.amount", column = @Column(name="previousReport_personalContribution"))
    } )
    private ReportCostValues previousReport;




}
```

Hope this helps !!!!!